# Where do you find the degrees Lintner for a particular malt?

Tags: mash, conversion

**Please note:** my example here of a 80°L crystal malt was a *bad example* since specialty malts have no diastatic power. However the same holds true for any base malt I looked for: I cannot find where their Linterns are listed *anywhere*.

---

I'm trying to calculate the diastatic power of my recipe which requires me to know the numerical "Lintners" rating of each grain in the bill.

So I go to my local homebrew store and ask them what the Linters are of several different grains in their store. They have no clue.

I go to NorthernBrewer.com and look at the product details for several of their malts. They report the SRM, the Extract % and Moisture Content (so I can at least estimate PPG), but not the Lintners.

Ditto for MoreBeer.com.

One of my grains is Crystal 80°L, so I google "Breiss caramel 80l malt sheet" and get a [sample malt analysis sheet](https://www.brewingwithbriess.com/wp-content/uploads/documents/Briess-PISB-Caramel-Malt-80L.pdf) from Breiss themselves and...nadda. No mention of Lintners. No mention of diastatic power.

So I ask: where the heck are we supposed to get this information from?

Comment: Crystal malts have no diastatic power.  The enzymes are gone as part of the crystal-malting process.  So you won't find any information on Lintners for crystal malts, nor most of the darker roasted malts.  Only base malts.  Where to find specific information, I'm not certain.  Should be on a spec sheet from the maltster, which a commercial brewer might have, but I haven't seen that information passed on at the homebrewer level.

Comment: Yeah this was a bad example. But the same holds true for base malts. Can't find their Lintner values anywhere other than 3rd party sites that list the Lintners for large lists of base malts. And then I wonder what _their_ sources are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Briess Typical Analysis Sheet](https://cervezomicon.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/briess_typicalanalysis_malts.pdf) might be of help. It lists Lovibond and Lintner for several Briess malts. It is from 2017, not sure how much things change over the seasons. If you give 'em a bunch of info, it looks like they'll give you [access to the latest one](https://www.brewingwithbriess.com/products/).

If it's still not what your looking for, they have [Contact](https://www.brewingwithbriess.com/contact/) link where you could run the question up the wire and see if you get a response.

Comment: Dingemans adds it for their pilsner malt, but it is in WIndisch-Kolbach units. There are calculators for conversion between them. They don't give it for their other base malts.

Comment: After doing some more digging it looks like the maltsters can give you this info if you are willing to either dig or ask -- thanks everyone